# Is it possible to create a dynamic calender only using html & css

Tags: html, css

If any one knows how to make a dynamic calender using only html4 and css.
I don't to use any other language.
If any one knows please refer me the link of that website or you can paste your code.
Thanks

Comment: no html and css are static..

Comment: No, HTML and CSS are static. You'll need to hardcode it, or use an alternative language like PHP or Javascript.

Comment: HTML and CSS can help you to design the calendar. To make it dynamic, you need to use JS.

Comment: Thanks to all  for helping me

Answer (score 1):

Some modern browsers (such as Google Chrome) will give you a nice dynamic date picker if you use the new [HTML5 `date` input type](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_date), but there is no way to do this using only HTML and CSS that works across all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

With javascript help you can do it, I am planing to do same thing for my events. Not implemented yet but this is what I am leaning on.

1. using `display:flexbox` feature to lineup calendar cells which I consider as `<div>` element. This way I can fit them to any screen size with some width limitation. I don't care I have M-T-W-Th-F-S-S fixed columns
2. Or use `display:grid` and set each cell `grid-column` and `grid-row` to exact grid location. This way you have a static grid and start calendar cells from the exact location.
3. pulling my event content from the server by using web services via AJAX calls or XmlHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried it and it is pure theoretical:
Setup a static html page for future and past calendar situations. With CSS you can define all as invisible except one. On the left and right you define a area with a hover option. Passing the hover area makes one invisble (the one you are on) and next to the right/left visible. The next 'page' has the same setup except one month back or forward. Its for sure a big effort ..